# How to filter pandas dataframe based on date value with exact match

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have been trying to filter my data frame for the specific date although the date is present in the data frame but it doesn't return any results

Data in Data frame based on query

```
df[df['Date'] > '2017-03-20']
```

returns this results

```
StaffID     Date        
90047   2017-03-20 19:00:00     
90049   2017-03-20 19:00:00     
90049   2017-03-27 19:00:00
```

although when i am running this query

```
df[df['Date'] == '2017-03-20']
```

or

```
df.loc[df['Date'] == '2017-03-20']
```

it returns me no results at all just an empty data frame

```
StaffID     Date
```

my data frame column types are

```
StaffID                int64
Date          datetime64[ns]
```

and i have tried above query by comparing data frame date with string as well as by converting the **string date** into **datetime64[ns]** still the same results any help please would be appreciated

Comment: add `df.Date=df.Date.dt.date`, before you filter

Comment: still the same results

Comment: @Waqar because '2017-03-20' is treated as '2017-03-20 00:00:00' which is obviously lesser than '19:00:00', so you need to filter on date as Wen said.

Comment: Did that still the same results @Wen

Comment: Great nvm it worked had to convert the matching date to either numpy.datetime64 or datetime.datetime.date thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use dt.date astype string then compare i.e

```
df[df['Date'].dt.date.astype(str) == '2017-03-20']
```

Output:

```
  StaffID                Date
0    90047 2017-03-20 19:00:00
1    90049 2017-03-20 19:00:00
```

Comment: this will be faster than above code: `df[df['Date'].dt.date == pd.to_datetime('2017-03-20')]` as no conversion to string required for each row.

Answer (score 1):

You can do string comparison

```
df[df['Date'].astype(str).str[:10] == '2017-03-20']


    StaffID Date
0   90047   2017-03-20 19:00:00
1   90049   2017-03-20 19:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The date i was using is **'2017-03-20 19:00:00'** which is > than **'2017-03-20 00:00:00'** thats why it wasn't comparing it right the best way to do it is

```
df.Date = df.Date.dt.date
dateToMatch = np.datetime64('2017-03-20')
df[df.Date == dateToMath]
```

above code returns

```
   StaffID     Date
0   90047   2017-03-20
1   90049   2017-03-20
```

this will only extract date from my date column and replace the old column which had time

Credit: Wen who answered me in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Dates tend to be a bit tricky, between datatype, format, and the like. It's pretty important to make sure you're comparing apples to apples.
For example, you can get

```
today = date.today()
thismonth = today.strftime("%m") #gives 09 not 9 for Sept
```

And it won't do you a bit of good if you're trying to compare it with a pandas date.
Heck, you can even cast it to int like this

```
m1 = today.strftime("%-m") #gives 9 for Sept
m2 = int(m1)
```

and it won't do you a damn bit of good.
That's because pandas has it's own pandas.Timestamp class that it uses for dates, with numpy datatypes.
For example:

```
df = df.loc[df['Date'].dt.month == m2
```

Won't work with the stuff above, because you're comparing int32 to int.
In this case you're comparing the int32 data type returned by pandas.Series.dt.month to an int.
It won't work and you'll get nada, nothing, zip, zilch, goose eggs.
Instead, you have to do:

```
m1 = pd.Timestamp.today()
df = df.loc[df['Date'].dt.month == m1.month]
```

I had to figure it out because I wanted to automatically filter by current month and amount of time it took me to figure out how to do it was just ungodly.